# Remove some specific elements in dataframe by indices

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45],
  "sex": ["F", "M", "F"]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = [0,1,2])
```

I want to remove a single data entry for index = 1 in the duration column, how can I supposed to do it? It's both okay to create a new df or edit the existing one.

Update:
Actually the df that I am dealing with is like:

```
   calories  duration sex
0       420        50   F
1       380        40   M
2       390        45   F
3                  60
```

And I would like to remove the 40 in duration column, is that possible?
I have used the df.drop() method but turned out the whole duration column is dropped.

```
   calories  duration sex
0       420      50     F
1       380      45     M
2       390      60     F
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What value do you want to insert?

Comment: How many rows do your dataframe have? It seems you dataframe does not have same length of column. The last row is not showing any index. Please provide clearer description of your dataframe.

Comment: `df.loc[1, 'duration'] = np.NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Set axis = 0 in df.drop

```py
df.drop([1] , axis=0)
```